# Connection Variable to use while joining separate Databases?

Tags: mysql, pdo

If i have two connection variables while using PDOs,
Say, **$conUser1** and **$conUser2**, for separate databases **DB1** and **DB2**.
And if I want to execute a query that joins tables from both databases, which connection variable should I use to begin and commit transactions?

Ex:-

```
$query = $conUser1->prepare("/* query joining two databases */");
$conUser1->beginTransaction();
    $query->execute();
$conUser1->commit();
```

but the problem is, how do I decide which variable to use?
I cannot begin and commit transactions for just one database, can I?

Comment: Im not sure but i think its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db1_connect = new PDO();
$db2_connect = new PDO();
$db1_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db2_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$query = "SELECT ....";
$statement1 = $db1_connect->query($query);
$statement2 = $db2_connect->query($query);

$results = array_merge($statement1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), $statement2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$combined = array();
foreach ($results as $key => $row){
    $combined[$key] = $row['combined'];
}
```